# Wrong font path in the next js build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, static, tailwind-css

I am using tailwin css and local fonts are stored inside the public folder and other configurations are as follows:

1. in global css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "GAS";
  src: url("/fonts/gas.TTF");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "MONUMENT";
  src: url("/fonts/monument.otf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "UNIVERSE";
  src: url("/fonts/universe.otf");
}
```

2. tailwind config:

```
extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        gas: "GAS",
        universe: "UNIVERSE",
        monument: "MONUMENT"
      }}
```

3. next config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  assetPrefix: ".",
  images: {
    unoptimized: true
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/home',
        permanent: true
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Now these fonts are working fine in local, but when I deploy the builds, font is not loading because of wrong path:

path coming: http://dev-games-rgs.sportsit-tech.net/fonts/universe.otf
path should be coming: http://dev-games-rgs.sportsit-tech.net/games/crash/fonts/universe.otf

Even though I configure "assetPrefix" but seems like it dosen't works for css files. Some help will be appreciated.

1. Tried to move fonts inside src folder, and used relative path instead but got worse
2. Tried to use next/font which quite new and didn't went well
3. Configured "assetPrefix" which solve problem of loading resources if under some jsx or js file, but not effective for css files [like even if I want setup background image from css won't work]